# SQL Left Join does not show all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following Query:

At the moment i get the following code:

It gives back only one tag not the three tags in the database.

The database looks like this:

In this Database are 3 tags with bm_tagslang = 'de' but i only get one.

Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the schema for all the tables and some raw data to test. Also, please clarify the question

Comment: The more details you provide the easier it is to solve the problems. But I believe you fixed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Move `tagslang.lang` into the `on` condition.  When there is no match, it is `NULL`, so it changes the `left join` to an `inner join`:

```
on blog.id = tagslang.blogid and tagslang.lang = ?
```

You also need to change the `group by`.  It should be:

```
group by blog.id
```

Otherwise, you may be grouping by a `NULL` value.

As a note:  Do not use columns in the `group by` that are not in the `SELECT`.  This is a MySQL (mis)feature that should not be used unless you really understand what you are doing.

Comment: i get the same result.